# Why can't my PowerShell script access a variable outside of a Click Event when compiled to exe?

Tags: powershell, object, user-interface, exe

I have a problem with using the Variable **$AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox** which is a Text Box Object in a Button Click Event when the script is compiled. It works fine when I run it in PowerShell itself but as soon as I compile it to an exe with **PS2Exe**, it won't work any more and gives me the **"Connection to Device Failed"** Error which should only appear when the **Test-Connection** doesn't result in Success.

I'm using Powershell Version 7.3.6 and PS2EXE-GUI v0.5.0.28

Here is the affected part of my code:

```
$AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(70, 255)
    $AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,15)
    $AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox.Text = "NBW03" #These few characters are used for every device here so I added them by default

#Other stuff

if (Test-Path "C:\TMP\tools\psexec.exe") {
        $AdmPSECMDStartButton.Add_Click{
            if ((Test-Connection ($AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox.Text) -Count 1).Status -eq "Success") {
                $PSEComputerName = "\\" + $AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox.Text
                $PSECom1 = '/k cd /d C:\Windows\System32 & "C:\TMP\tools\psexec.exe" -h -s '
                $PSECom2 = " cmd.exe"
                $combinedPSECommands = $PSECom1 + $PSEComputerName + $PSECom2
                Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList $combinedPSECommands -Verb RunAs
            } else {
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
                    "Connection to Device Failed!",
                    "Error",
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error #Icon
                )
            }
        }
    } else {
        $AdmPSECMDStartButton.Enabled = $false
        $AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox.Text = "PSExec.exe not found..."
        $AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox.Enabled = $false
    }

    $adminTab.Controls.Add($AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox)
    $adminTab.Controls.Add($AdmPSECMDStartButton)
```

I tried using `$global:AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox` which resulted in the same error.
I was thinking to create an external window for PSExec which would work but I kinda want it to be one.

Comment: Try using a SyncHash table:
`$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})`
and add GUI components to it like:
`$syncHash.AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`
Then use that in the event.
Also its not advisable to deploy PSExec out to devices, as its a tool that can aid hackers if they gain access.

Comment: @KG-DROID Thank you. It works.
Also, don't worry, it's only for my IT Department and not for the general people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a SyncHash table: $syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{}) and add GUI components to it like: $syncHash.AdmPSECMDComputerNameBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Then use that in the event. Also its not advisable to deploy PSExec out to devices, as its a tool that can aid hackers if they gain access.

comment by KG-DROID
Thank you again. :)

Comment: Note that you don't need a _synchronized_ hashtable in a script that uses WinForms without parallelism. Generally (I don't know how `ps2exe` factors in this), event handlers, which run in _child_ scopes of the caller, do _see_ variables defined in the caller's scope (due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping), but cannot be _updated_ directly (trying to do so would create a _local_ variable; the simplest workaround is to do `$script:callerVar = ...`). However, with variables containing _controls_ (instance of .NET reference types in general), you _can_ directly update their _properties_.

Comment: It would be good to understand whether use of `ps2exe` really necessitated a different approach and, if so, why, or whether its use is incidental to your problem.